# Array duplicate deletion in C#

Tags: c#

This is my code so far I have display all items in the array as the user enters and create an error message for duplicate numbers that deletes the duplicate and continues the loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace midterm
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size;
            Console.WriteLine("How many numbers will you enter?");
            size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] numbers = new int[size];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
                numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j)
                    {
                        if (numbers[j] == numbers[i])
                        {
                            int k = j;
                            while (k < size - 1)
                            {
                                numbers[k] = numbers[k + 1];
                                k++;
                            }
                            size--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Duplicate Removed:");
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I go to change the for loops around or add an error message then the program stops deleting the duplicates I am really stumped on this one can someone lend me a hand.

Comment: Don't use an array for this. Use [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) which doesn't allow duplicates

Comment: "change the for loops around or add an error message" - what exactly are you trying to change, and what doesn't work about it? I take it the code as it stands now works correctly?

Comment: If you must use arrays (and the namespace `midterm` suggests this is some kind of homework), you need to move the loops checking for duplicates (the second one) inside the loop that collects user input, otherwise you will have no chance to force the user to enter a different number. For the sake of sanity, it would probably be better to refactor the duplicate checking into a separate function.

Comment: Why not use a `Dictionary`?

Comment: As this looks like _homework_. Take a look at the [guidelines for asking homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: It's not really clear here what you mean by *delete the duplicate*. What's the duplicate? The new item or the old one? If it's the new one, then just check first and don't insert it if it's already there. Is the order important here?

Comment: Another simple optimization that is possible if you check items as you add them to the array is that you know the new item is at the end of your array and since your array contained no duplicates before you added the new item, you only need to search the *n-1* items currently in the array and compare them to the *nth* item. That will make your search O(n) rather than O(n2).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`LINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx), it has some great functions that can be used for collection manipulation. In your situation I would do the following:

[`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here filters the array to only unique values.

```
int[] initialArray = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] noDuplicates = initialArray.Distinct().ToArray(); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: I assume from the `namespace midterm` line in the OP's code that this is an exercise and he's supposed to develop the algorithm himself.

Comment: @dvnrrs Hah, quite probably! It's a shame, as .NET already provides the tools required! It's still technically correct, so I'll leave it there. Since it looks like homework, we shouldn't be providing a solution to the actual code anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `List` instead of `array`. A `List` will allow you to keep adding entries to it without having to specify the size.

With the list, you can check if entry exists already before adding it, so you wont have to `remove` or `delete`

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, use a `HashSet`

```
    HashSet<int> mySet = new HashSet<int>();

    //... 

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (!mySet.Add(number)) 
        {
             Console.WriteLine("That was a duplicate. Try again");
             i--;
        }
    }
```

If you must use arrays:

```
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
        int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (ExistsInArray(number, numbers)) 
        {
             Console.WriteLine("That was a duplicate. Try again");
             i--;
        }
        else 
        {
            numbers[i] = number;
        }
    }
```

And then:

```
 private static bool ExistsInArray(number, numbers)
 {
     // Your code to search numbers for number and return true if found
     // Left as an exercise for the OP
 }
```

One important note here is that it's a lot easier to check whether your array already contains the element you are trying to add than to remove it after the fact. If it already exists, just don't add it again.